# Extracting two substrings with specific starting characters from a long string and concatenating them

Tags: string, awk, sed, extract

I am attempting to extract two pieces of information from a long string containing much more than I need. I have a tab-delimited .txt file with the following format repeated for 115,000 lines:

```
TRINITY_DN89_c0_g1_i1   blastx  match_part  2   388 5.00e-73    +   1   Target=UniRef90_UPI0005D06956 2 388;hin=2;hsn=1;db=uniref;hs=1;hf=0;hsl=387;hil=618;ql=390;pi=88.37;qc=99.23;hc=20.87;d=PREDICTED  uncharacterized family 31 glucosidase KIAA1161-like;tax=Plutella xylostellaTRINITY_DN89_c0_g1_i1 blastx  match_part  2   388 1.00e-72    +   1   Target=UniRef90_A0A0N1IHR0 2 388;hin=3;hsn=1;db=uniref;hs=1;hf=0;hsl=387;hil=647;ql=390;pi=82.95;qc=99.23;hc=19.94;d=Uncharacterized family 31 glucosidase KIAA1161;tax=Papilio;go=GO:0004553,GO:0005975
```

What I would like to end up with is the beginning value, in this case "TRINITY_DN89_c0_g1_i1" appended to each of the values after "go=GO:" at the end of each line.

The output I am hoping for in this case is as follows:

```
TRINITY_DN89_c0_g1_i1=0004553       
TRINITY_DN89_c0_g1_i1=0005975
```

However, the characters after `TRINITY_` and `go=GO:` are different for each line and represent unique identifiers for transcripts in a transcriptome I've assembled along with the associated gene ontology term annotations.

Using awk or sed seems like a possibility for accomplishing this but I am unsure of how to extract these specific pieces, especially since some characters differ between lines.

Any help is very much appreciated!

As an update, I've gotten my data into the following format, which is definitely closer than before, thanks to help from @shellter:

```
TRINITY_DN30_c0_g1_i1=0004553,GO:0005975
TRINITY_DN89_c0_g1_i1=0004553,GO:0005975
TRINITY_DN89_c0_g2_i1=0004553,GO:0005975
TRINITY_DN63_c0_g1_i1=0004190
TRINITY_DN105_c0_g1_i1=0003964
TRINITY_DN123_c0_g1_i1=0016021,GO:0005524,GO:0005215
TRINITY_DN163_c1_g1_i1=0016021,GO:0005524,GO:0005215
TRINITY_DN163_c1_g1_i1=0016021
TRINITY_DN292_c0_g1_i1=0003677,GO:0006338,GO:0006357
TRINITY_DN223_c0_g1_i1=0005858,GO:0016887,GO:0003777,GO:0003341                                
TRINITY_DN223_c0_g1_i1=0005509,GO:0051014,GO:0045010,GO:0051016
TRINITY_DN284_c0_g1_i1=0007010
```

Now, my issue is that I would like to have 1 line per GO value, each starting with its associated transcript ID. For instance, I would like to change the first line above to:

```
TRINITY_DN30_c0_g1_i1=0004553
TRINITY_DN30_c0_g1_i1=0005975
```

and do the same for every line with multiple GO values. To be clear, lines may have one or more GO values and some lines have quite a few. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample data, here is test bed version

```
sed 's/ .*go=GO:/=/;s/,.*$//' <<< "TRINITY_DN89_c0_g1_i1   blastx  match_part  2   388 5.00e-73    +   1   Target=UniRef90_UPI0005D06956 2 388;hin=2;hsn=1;db=uniref;hs=1;hf=0;hsl=387;hil=618;ql=390;pi=88.37;qc=99.23;hc=20.87;d=PREDICTED  uncharacterized family 31 glucosidase KIAA1161-like;tax=Plutella xylostellaTRINITY_DN89_c0_g1_i1 blastx  match_part  2   388 1.00e-72    +   1   Target=UniRef90_A0A0N1IHR0 2 388;hin=3;hsn=1;db=uniref;hs=1;hf=0;hsl=387;hil=647;ql=390;pi=82.95;qc=99.23;hc=19.94;d=Uncharacterized family 31 glucosidase KIAA1161;tax=Papilio;go=GO:0004553,GO:0005975"
```

**output**

```
TRINITY_DN89_c0_g1_i1=0004553
```

The substitution patterns work like, "find the first space in the line and then match all the way to `go=GO:`. Replace all of that with `=`'. Same idea with `s/,.*$//`. This finds the first comma in the remaining text, and matches to the end-of-the-line `.*$`, and the replaces with `//` (nothing).

Given your data is in a file, you can just pass the filename as an argument to `sed`, and use shell redirection to write to a new file, i.e.

```
sed 's/ .*go=GO:/=/;s/,.*$//' file > outFile
```

This allows you to keep a backup of your original file, so if you discover a problem in the output, you don't have to spend time regenerating your original file (or copying it from your archive, or what ever).

If you're going to build this into a scripted solution, and you want to use the same filename throughout (regardless of the version of data inside), new versions of `sed` have the `-i` (inplace) option, so ...

```
sed -i 's.....' file
```

Will edit your file inplace.

If you're using this on Mac or other Berkely based versions of Unix/Linux, then you have to tell the `-i` option to not worry about a backup file, and use

```
sed -i"" 's....' file
```

IHTH

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response!

Comment: Your first suggestion when inputting the line directly into the command prompt works quite well but would be impossible for me to repeat with each line from my data file. Your second suggestion for use on the file itself does not seem to output the correct way and I am getting the following output for the first line:  TRINITY_DN30_c0_g1_i1 blastx match_part 260 517 1.00e-23 + 1 Target=UniRef90_UPI0006EAEBFB=0004553                       Do you have an idea what might fix this?

Comment: @ScottCinel : "first suggestion" : . Yep, that's the problem with small samples of data. "second suggestion" : Hm.. it should work. But that assumes that the first part of data you want to capture is always before the first space char in the line and that there is only one `go=GO:`. Without seeing more details of your data, I don't see an easy way to resolve this. AND (sorry but) I don't want to get involved in a two hour session of debugging your data. I"ve tried to give you a place to start.

Comment: Feel free to post a new Q with 2-3 lines of **smaller** sample data that still illustrates the range of possibilities but will be easier to work with. Good luck.

Comment: Hmm. I'm thinking I missed a key point to your problem. You want to retrieve **two** value pairs from each line of data? Another reason to make your data smaller (replace long strings of stuff that will be ignored with much shorter strings like "abc", "def", "xyz", etc.). Can you go back to the source and rebuild your data file so 1 line of data is output as 2 lines? That will probably simplify your problem. Edit your Q with your best version of sample data and put a small comment, and I'll look at it again later (or someone else will pick this up). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for staying with me and helping me out. Please see my update to the question above. Your original file-based command worked perfectly once I changed the space character to a tab. Please let me know if I should repost my update as a different question as I am new to StackOverflow. I appreciate your patience and willingness to help!

Comment: @ScottCinel Your question has gotten really messy, but if you have a file with the formatted output from @shellter's script then just run the following `awk -F, -v OFS="\n" '{split($1,ary,/=/);for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {split($i,arry,/:/); $i=ary[1] "=" arry[2]}; print $0}' file`. It could be done entirely in awk but I can't seem to follow the question properly.

Comment: @ScottCinel : I don't see a reason to post a new Q. We're really close. Now I see the 2nd GO:0005975 after the first. It should be pretty easy to fix this BUT I'm betting this is an open-ended data format, and that you can have 1 or more GO:nnnnnn elements OR will it always be **only** two elements.  I recmnd you  copy your Q into an editor and revise so it is a clean flow of thought. "I have this info, I need this output, describe any extra constraints on data or output and show what my current code is doing". If you're having problems with the `-i` thing, just use the first form ` ... >out`

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks so much to jaypalsingh and shellter for their help!